# Make paragraph change onclick from different buttons on HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I have 12 or so buttons on my HTML, and I want to change the text of just one paragraph after I click each button, because each button should deliver a different text. The problem is that, because I generated all the buttons through a Jinja loop (I'm running server in Flask) I only get the text from the LAST iteration of the loop, no matter which button I click. As you can see, I created the function that does the magic, but I don't know where to place it so I can get the text from each button separately. I hope this is not too obvious and someone'll be kind enough to respond. Please consider that I'm studying Python, so I'm below noob level on all things JS. Thanks a lot!

```
<table class="table">
      <tr>
          {%for i in days: %}
          <td>
              <table>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          {{ days[i] }}
                          <hr class="zero">
                      </th>
                  </tr>
                  {%for x in tasks: %}
                  {%if x.owner_id == i: %}
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <button  class="click" onclick="change_text()">{{ x.task_name }}</button>
                          <hr class="zero">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  {%endif%}
                  <script>
                  function change_text(){
                      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "{{ x.task_id }}";
                  }
                  </script>
                  {%endfor%}
              </table>
          </td>
          {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `change_text` needs a parameter where you can pass the text.

```
<script>
   function change_text (text) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
   }
</script>
```

Than you can write in your loop

```
{%for x in tasks: %}
{%if x.owner_id == i: %}
<tr>
  <td>
      <button  class="click" onclick="change_text('{{ x.task_name }}')">{{ x.task_name }}</button>
      <hr class="zero">
  </td>
</tr>
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

Also you should define your JS function not within a Jinja loop but outside.

Comment: Oh mate, you really made me a solid right here, thanks a lot!! I'll be more careful next time. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function changeText(text) {
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=text;

            }


        </script>

        <input type="button" value="Button 1" id="b1" onclick="changeText('First Button');"/>
        <input type="button" value="Button 2" id="b2" onclick="changeText('Second Button');"/>
        <input type="button" value="Button 3" id="b3" onclick="changeText('Third Button');"/>

        <p id="pText">Click on a Button</p>
```